# Network Error when trigger nuxt-link beginner

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

Network Error when trigger nuxt-link after refresh same page its work fine
Here is Template

```
<div class="col-lg-3" v-for="(video, index) in videos" :key="index">
       <nuxt-link :to="/video/ + video.id"> 
        <img :src="video.image" width="100%">
        <div class="card">
          
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="title">{{ video.title }}</h1>
          </div>
         
        </div>
      </nuxt-link>
      </div>
```

scripts

```
export default {
  layout: 'default',
  asyncData({ req, params }) {
    // We can return a Promise instead of calling the callback
    return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/getVideos')
      .then((res) => {
        return { videos: res.data.data }
      })
  }
}
```

Here is Next Page Link

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default{
        layout: 'default',
        asyncData({ req, params }) {
            // We can return a Promise instead of calling the callback
            return axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/video/${params.id}`)
           
              .then((res) => {
                return { video: res.data.video , relatedVideos: res.data.relatedVideos }
              })
          },
        
         
          
    }
</script>
```

[image]

and This is the Error what is and facing

after refresh page it works fine

Comment: check console for errors

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/video/cPsvklEauEA' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: so u have a error, its cors error. There milliards of articles of it in google and SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after install > https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors package in my laravel backend everything working fine

Comment: Please elaborate what this does. Link-only answers may become useless if the link stops working.

Comment: i added this package to my laravel application which i use as backend 
this package help me to add cors header